# Freespace after a bootcamp that i can't get back(mac)

Tags: macos, disk-utility, bootcamp, partition, error

I have encountered with a problem after corrupted bootcamp Windows deinstallation. In `diskutil list`  i have a free space and in GUI version of Diskutil when i'm trying to partition it - I keep getting an error.

`diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         600.0 GB   disk0s2
                    (free space)                         400.2 GB   -

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +600.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     336.8 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 5.9 GB     disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                2.4 GB     disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            10.1 GB    disk1s4
   5:              APFS Snapshot com.apple.os.update-... 10.1 GB    disk1s4s1
   6:                APFS Volume VM                      4.3 GB     disk1s5

/dev/disk2 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +240.1 MB   disk2
   1:                  Apple_HFS /Users/admin/build-A... 240.1 MB   disk2s1

/dev/disk3 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +1.8 GB     disk3
   1:                  Apple_HFS VMware Fusion           1.7 GB     disk3s1

/dev/disk4 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +15.0 MB    disk4
   1:                 Apple_APFS Container disk5         15.0 MB    disk4s1

/dev/disk5 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +15.0 MB    disk5
                                 Physical Store disk4s1
   1:                APFS Volume LayoutSwitcher          4.0 MB     disk5s1
```

An error after partitioning:

```
Running operation 1 of 1: Remove “Free space” and grow container disk1 “Macintosh HD”…

Operation failed because corruption was found in the startup container disk1 or one of its volumes. Run First Aid from Recovery to repair it, then try again. Click Done to continue.
```

logs:

```
Partitioning disk “APPLE SSD AP1024N Media” (disk0)

Running operation 1 of 1: Remove “Free space” ((null)) and grow container disk1 “Macintosh HD” (disk0s2)…
Aligning grow delta to 400,240,558,080 bytes and targeting a new container size of 1,000,240,963,584 bytes
Determined the maximum size for the APFS Container to be 1,000,239,935,488 bytes
Resizing APFS Container designated by APFS Container Reference disk1
The specific APFS Physical Store being resized is disk0s2
Verifying storage system
Using live mode.
Performing fsck_apfs -n -x -l /dev/disk0s2
Checking the container superblock.
Checking the checkpoint with transaction ID 1915027.
Checking the EFI jumpstart record.
Checking the space manager.
Checking the space manager free queue trees.
Checking the object map.
Checking the encryption key structures.
Checking volume /dev/rdisk1s1.
Checking the APFS volume superblock.
The volume Macintosh HD - Data was formatted by mobile_obliterator (2142.120.7) and last modified by apfs_kext (2235.60.6).
Checking the object map.
Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
Checking the snapshot metadata.
Checking the document ID tree.
Checking the fsroot tree.
error: inode with file-id 6416344 has doc-id 11389 but doc-id tree record has file-id 6429218
error: inode with file-id 6429218 has doc-id 11389 but doc-id is already in use
error: inode (id 6429218): xf 1/5: INO_EXT_TYPE_DOCUMENT_ID: invalid doc_id index
error: inode (id 6429218): invalid xfields
fsroot tree is invalid.
The volume /dev/rdisk1s1 with UUID FE6C3D1F-390D-4379-8351-AFF4E8EAD8E5 was found to be corrupt and needs to be repaired.
Checking volume /dev/rdisk1s2.
Checking the APFS volume superblock.
The volume Preboot was formatted by diskmanagementd (1412.141.1) and last modified by apfs_kext (2235.60.6).
Checking the object map.
Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
Checking the snapshot metadata.
Checking the fsroot tree.
Checking the extent ref tree.
Verifying volume object map space.
The volume /dev/rdisk1s2 with UUID 45EAFC35-0131-486A-AADC-338D9F1FEB7F appears to be OK.
Checking volume /dev/rdisk1s3.
Checking the APFS volume superblock.
The volume Recovery was formatted by diskmanagementd (1412.141.1) and last modified by apfs_kext (2235.60.6).
Checking the object map.
Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
Checking the snapshot metadata.
Checking the fsroot tree.
Checking the extent ref tree.
Verifying volume object map space.
The volume /dev/rdisk1s3 with UUID 2C31B08F-28CB-4431-82EB-E9436459535A appears to be OK.
Checking volume /dev/rdisk1s4.
Checking the APFS volume superblock.
The volume Macintosh HD was formatted by storagekitd (2235.41.1) and last modified by apfs_kext (2235.60.6).
Checking the object map.
Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
Checking the snapshot metadata.
Checking snapshot 1 of 1 (com.apple.os.update-0F23B273DE60A40F73D7EE5CBBB0D9C6DA7F0F7E002D346F1A4981B0ED0B67DD)
Checking the fsroot tree.
Checking the file extent tree.
Checking the extent ref tree.
Verifying volume object map space.
The volume /dev/rdisk1s4 with UUID 4678F58B-E885-4ADC-86B4-E31DC5651465 appears to be OK.
Checking volume /dev/rdisk1s5.
Checking the APFS volume superblock.
The volume VM was formatted by com.apple.MobileSof (2235.41.1) and last modified by apfs_kext (2235.60.6).
Checking the object map.
Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
Checking the snapshot metadata.
Checking the fsroot tree.
Checking the extent ref tree.
Verifying volume object map space.
The volume /dev/rdisk1s5 with UUID 515BCA8C-B16B-42CC-B461-B5EB3B55EE90 appears to be OK.
Checking volume /dev/rdisk1s6.
Checking the APFS volume superblock.
The volume Update was formatted by com.apple.Mobi (1677.141.3.7.2) and last modified by apfs_kext (2235.60.6).
Checking the object map.
Checking the snapshot metadata tree.
Checking the snapshot metadata.
Checking the fsroot tree.
Checking the extent ref tree.
Verifying volume object map space.
The volume /dev/rdisk1s6 with UUID FB090F43-D29D-493E-B8D1-92F2F265CDC0 appears to be OK.
Verifying allocated space.
Performing deferred repairs.
error: Unable to perform deferred repairs without full space verification
The container /dev/disk0s2 could not be verified completely.
Storage system check exit code is 8.
Storage system verify or repair failed. : (-69716)

Operation failed…
```

Comment: Evidentially, the *"operation failed because corruption was found in the startup container disk1 or one of its volumes."* Did you *"run First Aid from Recovery to repair it, then try again?"*

Comment: Yes i did. I tried many things from diffrent people's solution, but none of them works.